# Get name of excel worksheets in perl

Tags: perl, excel

I am a newbie to coding and perl.

I am trying to read names of excel worksheets in an excel file through Perl

Following is my code

```
#!/usr/local/ActivePerl-5.12/bin//perl -w

use strict;
use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;

my $FileName = "/Users/labuser/Desktop/TestAutomation/Results.xls";

my $parser   = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel->new();
my $workbook = $parser->parse($FileName);

die $parser->error(), ".\n" if ( !defined $workbook );

for my $worksheet ( $workbook->worksheets() ) {

print $worksheet;

}
```

But i am not able to get name of the worksheet through print $worksheet.
Please suggest how can i get that

Comment: @simbabque - note the -w on the shebang.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to use:

```
print $worksheet->get_name();
```

in place of

```
print $worksheet
```

Also use foreach:

```
foreach my $worksheet ($workbook->worksheets()) {
   print $worksheet->get_name();
}
```

Comment: i used this but got the error
Can't locate object method "sheets" via package "Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::Workbook" at /Users/labuser/Desktop/reading-excel 2.pl line 18.

Comment: 'for' is identical to 'foreach' ... no need to change ... it is completely a matter of preference.

Comment: @runrig: Agreed, i should not be dictating my preferences :)